# How to get the right string when given a corrupted one

Tags: string

Following is an interview question on Glassdoor which I haven't find a good solution.

Given a string length 25, consisting of alphabet (lower and upper case) and numbers. Now, in this string some of the upper case letters are lower cased. So it becomes a corrupted string. Suppose there is a black-box function that returns an integer, something like 13 or 14, which says the input string is correct else it throws an exception. How to find the right original string given this corrupted string?

Is there anyone having ideas about this question?

Thank you:)

Comment: The black-box function that returns an integer, what is the meaning of that integer? It returns any integer if the string is correct and throws an exception if incorrect?

Comment: I think the integer the useless. It only tells us the input string is correct.

Comment: I suppose, the question itself is not well defined, because they want to see how you can develop it and tell something about the question and solution. For example as Yogendra Singh answered, if the black-box function is working for substrings then the solution would be ... It is his way of thinking. And they can estimate how does person think. You should check the questions asked at Google's interview :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the black box function's (assuming it works for sub strings as well) declaration is as below:

```
    public Integer isCorrectString(String value) throws Exception;
```

We can write a small loop to correct your 25 length string as below:

```
    String inputString ="abcd...";
    for(int i=1; i<=25; i++){
            try{
                   isCorrectString(inputString.substring(0, i));
             }catch(Exception ex) {
                  //change the char at ith position to upper case as its incorrect
                  inputString = inputString.substring(0, i-1)+
                          inputString.substring(i-1, i).toUpperCase()+
                          inputString.substring(i+1);

             }
     }
```

After the loop, `inputString` should be corrected.

Comment: Who said that you can use that function for substrings? I can implement it as a function which checks the input string with a fixed string.

Comment: This is sample code with the idea as "scan the input string left to right one character at a time. Call the black box function. If it throws exception, change the case of last character in the sub-string and proceed". I have an assumption that the black-box function works for sub-string as well. I know we can implement this in more efficient way, but I am just trying to share the approach/possible solution.

Comment: Your solution is OK if your assumption is correct.
The question itself is not well set.

Comment: Thanks. This approach works for your assumption. But if the black-box function doesn't work for substrings, the solution might be more complicated.

Comment: Agree, but in the problem statement, it wasn't mentioned that it doesn't support sub-string. It just says- checks the string. So why should we complicate the problem ourselves upfront?

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward solution would be to change the lowercase letters in the input string to uppercase and check if the black-box function returns an integer value (not exception). Every combination should be checked. The number of combinations in the worst case would be 2 to the power 25 minus 1

Comment: Yes, this is a brute force solution. The candidate also gives this solution during the interview. I'm wondering whether there is some better solution.